# There was an error parsing the body when calling an API

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle

i'm working on an OCR project and i'm trying it using vidado API. when i send a post request through the posman it gives me the correct response but when i calling API from php it gives me below error

```
Client error: `POST https://api.vidado.ai/read/text` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"detail":"There was an error parsing the body"}
```

my code is

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
                $url   = "https://api.vidado.ai/read/text";

                $requestAPI = $client->post( $url, [
                    'headers' => [
                        'Accept' => 'application/json',
                        'Authorization' => 'my apikey',
                        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
                    ],
                    'form_params' => [
                        'autoscale' => 'true',
                        'image'=> $img
                    ],
                ]);
```

in postman my request is like below
[image: request header]
[image: request body]

any one noticed the actual error? so please give me a way to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: What you put inside $img?

Comment: @krylov123 image object

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoring to [Guzzle documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html)

> Note
>
> multipart cannot be used with the form_params option. You will need to
> use one or the other. Use form_params for
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests, and multipart for
> multipart/form-data requests.
>
> This option cannot be used with body, form_params, or json

So you can't use form_params with multipart/form-data and you have to use multipart approach this way:

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url   = "https://api.vidado.ai/read/text";

$requestAPI = $client->request('POST', $url, [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'my apikey',
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
    ],
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'image',
            'contents' => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r'),
            'filename' => 'custom_filename.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'autoscale',
            'contents'=> true
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me, But still i'm getting the same error. Here is the my path to file and file name   "/home/madusanka/OX/ocr/storage/app/public/uploaded_images/3/selections/1.png",

"1.png"

Comment: it workes when remove the Content-Type key from the headers section. i could find the reason from  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550801/multiple-files-uploaded-via-guzzle-multipart-form-data-request-are-not-recognize] Thank you for answering.